# Install app on Motorola Backflip from AT&T

Tags: android, installation, motorola

I'm trying to test an app out on the Motorola Backflip with AT&T as the carrier.  I checked USB debugging on the phone's Development screen.

Using Eclipse, how do I get the app to load on the Backflip so I can test it?  DDMS shows a device with a bunch of question marks and unkown.  Seems that it only gives me the option to load the app on the SD card which doesn't do me any good.

I searched and found a Motorola driver which I'm supposed to install to the adb folder.  Where is that folder?  I've checked the phone and on my development machine.  Maybe I need new glasses?

More info:

I have Run set to manual.  When I click on run I get:

Choose a running Android Device:

Serial number ????????

AVD Name N/A

Target Unk

State ??

and the OK button is greyed out so all I have left is to Cancel.

Still trying:

I don't know if this helps but in DDMS the following messages show up:

[2010-03-28 19:20:41 - ddms]execute: running ls -l /

[2010-03-28 19:20:41 - ddms]Got reply 'FAIL', diag='insufficient permissions for device'

[2010-03-28 19:20:41 - ddms]execute: returning

Did what Commonwares suggested:

```
eric@i7Linux:~/Eclipse3.5/android-sdk-linux_86/tools> ./adb kill-server
eric@i7Linux:~/Eclipse3.5/android-sdk-linux_86/tools> ./adb kill-server
eric@i7Linux:~/Eclipse3.5/android-sdk-linux_86/tools> ./adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now *
* daemon started successfully *
eric@i7Linux:~/Eclipse3.5/android-sdk-linux_86/tools> ./adb devices
List of devices attached
????????????    no permissions

eric@i7Linux:~/Eclipse3.5/android-sdk-linux_86/tools>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.  Easier than I thought and I don't know how I missed that post.

If you are running Linux (I'm running Suse 11.2 x64) go to http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/device.html for full instructions.  I created the 51-android.rules file and I was able to install the app on the Motorola Backflip to test it.  (Needless to say, but I'll say it anyway, more testing required.  The layout on the Backflip doesn't match the emulator)

Repeating the instructions in the link:

1. Login as root
2. go to your etc/udev/rules.d folder
3. create a file called 51-android.rules
4. I put this line in the file:  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"
5. save the file

Instructions say to chmod a+r the 51-android.rules file but I didn't have to.  Permissions should be -rw-r--r--

Eclipse now sees the phone and I can load directly to it from Eclipse.

Back to coding :-))

Answer (score 1):

First, try `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server` (or just reboot your development machine). Then, with the device plugged in, run `adb devices`. If your device shows up (and with a real device ID, not question marks or anything), try it again from Eclipse, or use `adb install ...` (where `...` is the path to your APK) to install it.

Since the Backflip does not support app installs outside of the Market, there was a fair bit of public experimentation to ensure the Backflip supported `adb`-based installs, so I know it works in general.

Comment: CommonsWare,  Thanks but see my edited post.  All I got was question marks.

Comment: Where is the adb folder located?

Comment: `adb` is located in `$ANDROID_SDK/tools`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is where you installed the SDK. It also appears to be in your path from your edited question. See http://groups.google.com/group/android-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f85a795644e65b59 and http://notannoidwithdroid.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-device-and-usb-driver.html and http://androidboss.com/using-android-debug-bridge-adb-in-linux/ for more advice. Beyond that, try a different micro USB cable, or reboot the phone.

Comment: CommonsWare, Thanks.  I rebooted the phone and still a bunch of question marks.  I doubt it's the USB cable as the phone is charging now.  I posted on the MotoBlur website to see if that would help me:  http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Studio-for-Android/Backflip-connect-to-PC/m-p/4900#M560 here.  Hope this link came out ok.

Comment: FWIW, I have had some problems with USB cables that charge but don't do data properly. I don't think it is very common, but it has happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse. when you run the application it should automatically set your phone as the target and push the apk to the phone and execute it.  You might have to set your phone as the target instead of the emulator.

Comment: Thanks.  Please see post for More Info: